# JavaScript - how to remove certain whitespaces in string

Tags: javascript, regex

For Example, I have a string like this:

```
"1 - A1, 2 - A2, 3 - A3";
```

I want to remove the white spaces ONLY after the commas, NOT the white space in between the hypens "-" so end result looks like this:

```
"1 - A1,2 - A2,3 - A3";
```

currently I'm doing:

```
myString.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

but this removes all whitespace, including whitespace on both sides of the hyphens. I just want to remove the whitespace after the commas.

Is this doable?

Thanks

Comment: How about just replacing `', '` with `','`, no regex needed?

Comment: @spender and the result would be `"1 - A1,2 - A2, 3 - A3"`

Comment: `replace(", ", ",")` removes only the first instance. It will not remove the space bewteen the second instance. Run it.

Comment: Regex is ', ' replacement is ',' exactly what @spender said

Comment: @AyushBaunthiyal: Not exactly, spender wrote **no regex needed**

Comment: Can be done with or without regex, but not without regex through `String.prototype.replace` as it needs the `g` flag for all coincidences.

Comment: @anubhava yeah this is just find and replace you can't its a regex because it is not using any complex character grouping or special literals its like saying every natural number is rational number because it is divisible by 1 that is understood

Comment: @epascarello Well, don't you know..! I never knew that... it was a trap waiting for me to fall into it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
var str = "1 - A1, 2 - A2, 3 - A3";
var r = str.replace(/,\s+/g, ',');
//=> "1 - A1,2 - A2,3 - A3"
```

`,\s+` will all commas with at least one whitespace afterwards.

Comment: damn.. I guess I should have at least tried to understand how my replace method works, might have been able to figure this out myself! haha but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution if there is always exactly one whitespace character after those commas:

```
"1 - A1, 2 - A2, 3 - A3".split(", ").join(",");
```